# Can't open wp-admin in Safari - "server unexpectedly dropped the connection"

Tags: php, wordpress, safari, mamp

Hi I have installed a Wordpress theme in my MACBOOK pro successfully (after downloading MAMP & creating wordpress database of course).

When i open localhost:8888/wordpress - it all looks good. I am now trying to open this link: localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-admin to be able to customise the theme. I encounter error.

The error in safari says: "Safari can't open the page because the server unexpectedly dropped the connection).

Here is the image
[image]

I have tried all trouble shooting guides i found and they DID NOT WORK:
- Changing the speed in my apache setting 
- Remove cache in my safari (Safari  > Preferences > Privacy > Remove all website data)
- Clean up my MacBook to free up 4gb of RAM
- In my terminal command: sudo purge

Please help! My goal is to be able to open: localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-admin and customize the theme in my local computer.

Comment: Look at the Apache server logs and find out what it is doing.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [WordPress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

Here are steps to fix this...

In Safari

> Menu bar > Preferences > Privacy > Remove all website data

On prompt select

> Remove Now

All cookies will be cleaned up & now test your website is working or not.

It should start working as normal. 
Hope this helps.